# How do I force Drupal ImageCache create image styles on upload, not on first image request?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, image-caching

I am using [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) to generate several image styles for certain uploaded pictures. However, the site is going to be pretty high-load, so it might be more resource-efficient, if those sizes were created once the file is uploaded, not on first display event.
Is there any way meant to do this without having to use some kind of crawler? Thank you!

Comment: This might be the answer your looking for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42710/how-do-i-programmatically-get-a-styled-version-of-an-image-via-imagecache-in-d7

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to create custom cron function which get all latest uploaded images and build imagecache versions.

Check pretty similar question here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38/rebuild-imagecache.

Comment: Actually it is the very thing i'd like to avoid, as soon as rebuilding the whole cache in terms of GD resourse consumption is headache. What I want is to build cache for uploaded image at once, on the upload or update event, not giving ooportunity that some search bot etc. will rebuild the whole lot of images

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a module for that:
https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache